# Flutter/Dart - Suggestions for how to Troubleshoot a Future?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, future, snapshot

Though it was working previously, for some reason my code has now stopped working. Though it fetches the required json data, the build doesn't render. The error on my app page which is supposed to display a page view was;

```
type String is not a subtype of 'Map<String,dynamic>'
```

But after some tweaks, now the error is;

```
invalid arguments(s)
```

I think I may have narrowed it down to the Future;

```
FutureBuilder<List<SpeakContent>> futureStage() {
  return new FutureBuilder<List<SpeakContent>>(
    future: downloadJSON(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
       print("Snapshot has data.");
        List<SpeakContent> speakcrafts = snapshot.data;
        return new CustomPageView(speakcrafts);
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('${snapshot.error}');
      }
      return new CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  );
}

Future<List<SpeakContent>> downloadJSON() async {
  final jsonEndpoint =
      "http://example.com/getContent.php?";    
  final response = await get(jsonEndpoint);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {    
    List speakcrafts = json.decode(response.body);
    debugPrint(speakcrafts.toString());
    return speakcrafts
        .map((speakcraft) => new SpeakContent.fromJson(speakcraft))
        .toList();
  } else
    throw Exception('We were not able to successfully download the json data.');
}
```

Although it doesn't throw an error, I've noticed that it doesn't print my test statement after the "if (snapshot.hasData)" line.

Shouldn't I see "Snapshot has data." appear in my Android Studio console?

Comment: might be because you future never resolves / never returns. You could move up the future in the builder function or to the widget / state, save it in a variable like `final downloadFuture = downloadJSON()`, then use `future: downloadFuture`, and add a `downloadFuture.then` callback to check if it truly resolves.

Comment: Can you show method `downloadJSON`?

Comment: As requested I've just edited and included the downloadJson Claudio Redi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you provided, this

```
type String is not a subtype of 'Map<String,dynamic>'
```

must be this:

```
return Text('${snapshot.error}');
```

which means that your `downloadJSON()` threw an exception. In that case, `print('Snapshot has data.');` never executes and the next case that I quoted above is executed.

Please put a breakpoint in the body of `downloadJSON()`, run it line by line and see what's thrown where.

ALSO, you are making an irrelevant but big mistake here. Do not call `downloadJSON()` like this. This function is executed at every re-render, which can be many times. You are initiating a JSON download at every redraw of your widget. This may stack up your backend bills... I explain it in this talk in more detail: https://youtu.be/vPHxckiSmKY?t=4771

Comment: Thanks! I now know it's getting as far as to retrieve the jSon data because putting debugPrint(speakcrafts.toString()); just after List speakcrafts = json.decode(response.body) produces the required json data in the console.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. Btw, `type String is not a subtype of 'Map<String,dynamic>'` means you are doing such an assignment `'Map<String,dynamic>' 
= String`

Answer (score 0):

After performing the troubleshooting tips as suggested by Gazihan Alankus and scrimau, I've found the culprit which was a single null entry in the MYSQL Database. Scary... gotta find out how to prevent that problem in the future.

Comment: Makes sense, that null entry is probably getting converted to an empty string rather than a map during json parsing, which is why you get that error.